# Posts don't align properly in 2 columns

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't have much experience in coding but i am trying to learn:)

I am trying to edit the theme (Bhost from wordpress.org) to display first post separately as normal and the rest in 2 columns.

My issue is: when the title of the post is too long,it creates a gap between posts. The code from index.php:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php if ( !$wp_query->current_post > 0 ): ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class="post-row col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php if ( the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb') ) { has_post_thumbnail();} ?></a>
<?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="rest-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
    <span class="meta-data"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></span>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

```
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Better shown on the screenshot:

[image]

I can't figure out how to fix this :(

I tried tutorial #4 from [here](https://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/) and couple more but it is the same gap over and over again.

Appreciate some help. Sorry for my English. Thank you

Comment: Please include a code snippet from your theme.

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

The third post isn't able to fit because below the first because of the second line of the header pushing down. If you can set a height for the first row this should fix your problem.

Comment: Of course, I ran into that exact same problem when I started my journey in front end development. Pick my answer if it really helped ;-)